# Will the the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control continue to work following the Microsoft announcement to end support for Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: winforms

With Microsoft's recent announcement to [retire Internet Explorer 11](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/MessageCenter/:/messages/MC257152), will the Winforms WebBrowser control continue to function or is there a replacement control that should be used instead?

Comment: It will continue functioning as long as you don't use it to render non supported features. Besides, you won't get any support/updates/upgrades from MSFT for this control anymore else. For future apps, use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms).

Comment: Cheers dr.null.